# Change model before Form Submit in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model, form-submit

I have created the following form:

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Export", "ExportDefinitions", FormMethod.Post, new { ExportModel = Model }))
{
    <input name="button" type="submit" value="Export" />
}
```

Above this form is a  object, allowing multiple ID's to be selected.  This needs to be submitted as well.

The C# "ExportDefinitions" defines are:

```
public string SelectedIds { get; set; }

public bool OnlyForSelected { get; set; }
```

If there anyway to change the contents of "Model" before submitting the form?

I have some check thats need to be done first, which will modify the desired outcome if needs be.

New to MVC so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Any checks should be done using either an `Attribute` or in the Controller. You should not be doing smart-ish stuff in your View, assuming that's what you're asking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use attributes like minlength, required etc in the model's properties
like so

```
[Required]
public string SelectedIds { get; set; }

public bool OnlyForSelected { get; set; }
```

then you could do a ModelState.IsValid check in your view before posting. But imho doing form validations with jquery is a lot easier and more efficient.

Comment: You should always be doing both: client and server side validation.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use  System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations, 
A basic tutorial about this can be found here, [basic tutorial abount DataAnnotations;](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions/mvc-music-store/mvc-music-store-part-6/)

Its a  bad practice to have intelligent code for  validation in your view.